# Sql recursive query to read hierarchical data

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, db2

I am trying to come up with a SQL query to read recursive data as below :

```
ParentId    ChildId
    1          2
    2          3
    3          4
    4          5
    4          6
    8          9
```

If a `ParentId` is provided, then the query should return all `ChildId`s in a recursive manner.

Example : `parentId =1` , `result = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`

I found that `connect_by_root` and `connect by prior` is what I should be probably using it. However I am not able to get it right.

Database : Oracle and Db2

Comment: this will be a good place to start - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: There is an excellent Webminar about how to use SQL for hierarchies in DB2: http://www.idug-db2.com?commid=105565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it :

```
   SELECT childid
   FROM btab
   START WITH parentId = 1
   CONNECT BY PRIOR  childId = parentId;
```

Thanks to #Bulat & #AngocA, for the pointers

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT ChildId, ParentId, LEVEL
   FROM myTable
   CONNECT BY PRIOR ChildId = ParentId;
```

Comment: "Nope doesnot" what exactly? more details will be helpful

Comment: It needed the "Start with"